# Survival Rates of Firms

Tags: industrial-organisation, academic-graduate

Jovanovic (1982) cites Du Rietz (1975) as a source for

- Survival Rates of smaller firms are smaller than for larger firms

It's his doctoral thesis, and using Swedish data. Is there any recent evidence on this for the United States?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unlikely to be a published result in its own right, simply since it is publicly available [here](http://www.census.gov/ces/dataproducts/bds/data_firm.html)  (click on the row Firm Age).

Comment: The question is about size dependence rather than age dependence. But anyway, both are related and your tables do not really allow to disentangle them.